# Returning formula argument 'as is'

Tags: r

Suppose I have a function like this:

```r
my_lm <- function(formula, data) {
  lm(formula, data)
}
my_lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, iris)
```

I'd LIKE it to return something like this:

```r
Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
     6.5262      -0.2234
```

But instead, it returns this:

```r
Call:
lm(formula = t, data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
     6.5262      -0.2234
```

How do I make this happen? I'm assuming non-standard evaluation or environments are involved, but vague and hand-wavey is as good of an answer as I can provide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way to do this is to hack the relevant components of the `$call` element of  the model. The formula is easy because formulas are already unevaluated/symbolic objects. To get the correct result for `data` you need `substitute(data)`:

```r
my_lm <- function(formula, data) {
  m <- lm(formula, data)
  m$call$formula <- formula
  m$call$data <- substitute(data)
  m
}
my_lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, iris)
## Call:
## lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
##      6.5262      -0.2234
```

Answer (score 4):

We can just wrap the function body in `eval(bquote())` and the `data` in `substitute()` and then evaluate both `formula` and `data` early with `.()`:

```r
my_lm <- function(formula, data) {
  eval(bquote(
    lm(.(formula),
       .(substitute(data))
       )
    ))
}
}
my_lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, iris)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
#>      6.5262      -0.2234
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: this is definitely the other right answer. I think might require a little less abstract thought (i.e. figuring out what `eval(bquote(..., substitute()))` means ...